# Does the mobile app have a 'cache'?

Tags: support, bug, android-app, notifications, mobile-app

The Android app shows notifications for deleted things even after refreshing.

Is this a bug? Or is there some cache present?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also, the notifications in the app only show the *original* comment - not the edited version, if there is one

Comment: Not really a cache, rather it's not deleting the comments from the inbox when they are deleted from the site. It's the same in iOS app and as for edits, it's by design, also in the full site itself.

Comment: What does the update button do then? Does it just get new items rather than re-'download' the items that exist?

Comment: Yes, it loads new items only as far as I can tell.

Comment: ... Even if they don't exist